# Animate label count in with CABasicAnimation in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, animation

I have added a `CABasicAnimation` on `CAShapeLayer`.Now in this animation my `CAShapeLayer` create an arc on circle with animation.

Now what I want when this animation proceed count of label should increase with a sync to animation of `CAShapeLayer`. PLease how can I do it?

```
let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "strokeEnd")
//animation.delegate = self
animation.duration = 2
animation.fromValue = 0
animation.toValue = 0.7 // changed here
animation.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionLinear)
animation.isRemovedOnCompletion = false

progressCircle.add(animation, forKey: "ani")
```

Here `ProgressCircle` is the `CAShapeLayer`.

I used below code for increement label count with animation but it does not match with the animation.

```
func incrementLabel(to endValue: Int) {
        let duration: Double = 1.0 //seconds
        DispatchQueue.global().async {
            for i in 0 ..< (endValue + 1) {
                let sleepTime = UInt32(duration/Double(endValue) * 1000000.0)
                usleep(sleepTime)
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.label.text = "\(i)"
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Might be help!! follow this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14452086/how-to-animation-a-label-on-circular-path-in-ios

Comment: I think the OP is looking to animate the text of the label rather than the position of the label.

Comment: Yes i want to animate the text count like score on scoreboard.

Comment: @TechChain did you ever achieve a solution for this?